# Charts with MySQL and Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, google-visualization, jfreechart

I've been looking through examples online about charting libraries to work with in a Java Web Application but they all keep trying to implement some form of php to get the data before the chart is produced.

Ideally I would like to use google charts and then take data from my database through jsp/ servlet of some sort but I can't find any examples online without php.

I've tried Jfreechart but again can't find much documentation.

question I'm trying to ask is, How would I be able to draw charts that get data from MySQL and display them on my web page. All this is in Netbeans currently.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check iReport Designer. http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer

Comment: iReports uses jfreechart also

Comment: How would I import what I made from IReport designer into my web application?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using  jsp/servlets, have you considered using Java Server Faces? You can find an explanation of the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732).

If you were to use Java Server Faces, you would then be able to use [PrimeFaces Charts](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/barChart.jsf) to create something like this:

[image: PrimeFaces Chart]

You can see a full set of examples at the PrimeFaces website, and there is a tutorial on creating Generating a JavaServer Faces 2 Application [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html#completedProject) that covers creating an appplication lined to a MySQL database.

Using this method, you would place the chart data inside a bean and then reference it (the bean) from your webpage.

If you want to use JFreeChart, you can use [`ChartUtilities#saveChartAsXXXX`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html) to save an image of the chart on the server and then include a link to the the generated image inside your webpage.